# How do I extract text from a URL path in R?

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I have a dataframe, with a column with entries in the format of:

```
/textIwant
/textIwant/otherstuff
/
```

I want to create a new column extracting the "textIwant". Should I be using strsplit, or regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to extract one or more characters that are not a `/`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1,  "[^/]+")
#[1] "textIwant"   "textIwant"   "abc-def-ghi" "abc-def-ghi"
```

---

Or with `sub` from `base R` to match the characters that are not a `/`, capture it as a group (`([^/]+)`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`)

```
sub("^.([^/]+).*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "textIwant"   "textIwant"   "abc-def-ghi" "abc-def-ghi"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("/textIwant", "/textIwant/otherstuff", "/abc-def-ghi/", "/abc-def-ghi")
```

Comment: Don't you there might be more `textiwant` in the same line? give also the option of `str_extract_all`. +1

Comment: @akrun thank you! however, I am noticing that this is not properly extracting 'textIwant' when it contains hyphens in it. For example, if the entry is /abc-def-ghi/ or /abc-def-ghi, then your solution only extracts the 'abc' portion. How would we get everything?

Comment: @bayesian.asian  the `sub` option should take care of that if I am not mistaken\

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
basename(str1)
[1] "textIwant"   "otherstuff"  "abc-def-ghi" "abc-def-ghi"
```

Where `str1` comes from akrun's example:

```
str1 <- c("/textIwant", "/textIwant/otherstuff", "/abc-def-ghi/", "/abc-def-ghi")
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `strsplit()` with a split on `/` can be used.

```
sapply(strsplit(str1, "/"), "[", 2)
# "textIwant"   "textIwant"   "abc-def-ghi" "abc-def-ghi"
```